# Hashicorp vault secrets not fetched in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, vault

I have created some secrets in vault, and I'm passing the variables as below. But the secrets are not fetched.

```
annotations:
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject: 'true'
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-vault-addr: 'https://vaultadd.com'
        vault.hashicorp.com/auth-type: 'approle'
        vault.hashicorp.com/auth-path: 'auth/approle'
        vault.hashicorp.com/auth-config-role-id-file-path: '/vault/custom/role-id'
        vault.hashicorp.com/auth-config-secret-id-file-path: '/vault/custom/secret-id'
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-extra-secret: 'mysecret'
        vault.hashicorp.com/role: 'myrole'
        vault.hashicorp.com/auth-config-remove_secret_id_file_after_reading: 'false'
        vault.hashicorp.com/log-level: 'debug'
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-MY-SECRET: 'secret/mysecret/secrets'
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-MY-SECRET: |
             {{ with secret "secret/mysecret/secrets" -}}
               export username={{ .Data.username}}
               export password={{ .Data.password }}
             {{- end }}
```

And in Args I have mentioned below

```
args:
            ["sh", "-c", "source /vault/secrets/config && MY_ENTRYPOINT"]
```

Comment: you are using KV version 1 or KV version 2? if 2 you need to use `{{ with secret "secret/data/mysecret/secrets" -}}` and `{{ .Data.data.xxxx}}`

and seem like you're wrongly assign the `args` seem like it need to change to `"source /vault/secrets/MY-SECRET && MY_ENTRYPOINT"`

and could you share the vault-agent-injector logs?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use [environment](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/platform/k8s/injector/examples#environment-variable-example) variable annotation instead of file template annotation.

Please change the annotation as below

```
vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-config: 'secret/mysecret/secrets'
vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-config: |
             {{ with secret "secret/mysecret/secrets" -}}
               export username={{ .Data.username}}
               export password={{ .Data.password }}
             {{- end }}
```

Comment: You have done the same way I have done know. Nothing seems to be different in your code

Comment: The annotation used in sample provided are different and it’s for environment variables.   Also it’s matched to variables you had used.

Comment: I'm using approle auth method and it requires all the parameters mentioned.

Comment: The annotation given can be used along with Auth annotations.  Auth related annotations need not to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest KV2 the path to the secret is `<KV2-root-path>/data/<path-within-the-kv2>`

So if your KV2 is called `secret` then: `... with secret secret/data/mysecret/secrets ...`

Is the vault agent sidecar injected though? Does it have any logs?